# Unknown DOM element with value "/n" in asp.net website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, line-breaks

I have an ASP.NET website. Sometimes, an unknown DOM element with value "/n" appears in the source. Inspecting with Firebug shows that the HTML code is `&#65279;`. Of course, I never added this code myself. It makes a long distance between two elements. Is there any way to prevent this?
Here is HTML:

```
<div id="ctl05_pnWareHouse">
    &#65279;<div class="detail_content_right_top">
        <div class="detail_content_top_left">
            <p class="name_content">
                ...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may have pasted it from somewhere. It's a "zero width non-breakable space". @Adidi Dropping asp.net is not a solution.

Comment: @Adidi - ASP.NET may not be your favorite platform, but this is not the forum to say so.

Comment: @Adidi stackoverflow itself is built on ASP.net, it can't be all bad. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 1):

Building on **bfavaretto**'s comment:

An invisible Unicode character may have sneaked into your code during a cut & paste. If this happened, your server-side source code may look fine, but ASP.NET is noticing a character you can't see, then encoding it as HTML.

As for how to fix it, try this:

1) Open the server-side code in your editor.

2) Manually highlight everything from the `>` in `<div id="ctl05_pnWareHouse">` to the `<` at the beginning of `<div class="detail_content_right_top">`

[image]

3) Replace the characters there manually; i.e. type `>`, then enter, then `<`.

See if that solves your problem.